# UItableview on one click multiple cell are getting checked swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am having a problem in uitableview whenever I select one cell 4th no cell auto get selected... I am tired of this problem someone please help here is my didselectrowfunc..

```swift
////////////////For Adding Check Box////////////////////////

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    {
        if selectedDisease.count > 0
        {
            let no = selectedDisease.index(of: finall[indexPath.row])
            selectedDisease.remove(at: no!)
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
            print(selectedDisease)
        }
        else
        {
            selectedDisease = [""]
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if selectedDisease.contains("")
        {
            selectedDisease.removeAll()
            var name = finall[indexPath.row]
            selectedDisease.append(name)
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
            print(selectedDisease)
        }
        else
        {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
            selectedDisease.append(finall[indexPath.row])
            //selectedDisease = [finall[indexPath.row]]
            print(selectedDisease)
        }
    }
}

/////////CellForRowAt///////////////

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "diseasetable", for: indexPath) as! FoodTableViewCell

    cell.DiseaseName.text = finall[indexPath.row]
    //indexsave.append(indexPath.row)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: That is because table cells are reusable.What are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to let user select multiple disease but the issue is how to do that by this code its selecting automatically different cells.....   **And I Know it's reusing cell but how to overcome this that when table reuse cell it is not checked**

Comment: Add the code of cellForRow method also

Comment: it's added now @NiravD

Comment: @HammerClass The problem is basically this that you are not saving which cell you have tapped and which not. when the cell is reused the your first cell is reused on 4th and so you checkbox. You need to save which cells you have tapped, into some structure and check from it into cellForRowAtIndexPath for the checkBox value.

Comment: any suggestion how to do this......???? @ArunK

Comment: @HammerClass like you have saved the disease name data in finall named array, use a array in of booleans in which should have equal number of elements to that of finall array. this array of boolean should have false initially at every elements. from this array check if indexpath.row is false then don't show checkmark. when user tap then change the value of this array to true and reloadData of tableView

Comment: Thanks A lot man @ArunK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this logic hope this will solve your problem

```
    let dict = [NSIndexPath: String]()

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

         if let _ = // dict contains value at indexpath {
             cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
         } else {
             cell.accessoryType = .None
         }

         return cell
     }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
          if ( // dict contains value == indexpath) {
              // remove value from dict
          } else {
          //add value to dict
          }
          tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just take the advantage of `prepareForReuse` method of `UITableViewCell`. In your `FoodTableViewCell` class implement the `prepareForReuse` menthod like following

```
class FoodTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
   override func awakeFromNib() 
   {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      // Initialization code
   }
   override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) 
   {
      super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
      // Configure the view for the selected state
   }
   override func prepareForReuse()
   {
       self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none 
       //add code to reset selection if there is any other selection mechanism
   }
}
```

Comment: by using this method when i scroll down and comeback the selected cell are automatically unchecked... @raki

Comment: add selection logic inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, that will solve your issue